# How can I fill in C++ a vector of pairs from an array of strings having format "a:b"?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

How can I fill in C++ a vector of pairs from an array of strings following string having following format: "a:b", "c:d", "e:f"
For example:
string a[] = {"6:7","3:5","5:2"};
convert it to vector> and pair content is from 6 and 7,  then 3 and 5...

I didn't succeed with boost::lexical_cast nor with strtol, maybe to use regex? any other idea?

Thx

Comment: Yes, you can use regex.

Comment: it depends if you need to validate your input. If yes then regex would be a good choice - "(\\d+):(\\d+)"

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is probably to use a stringstream to handle the conversion:

```
std::pair<int, int> cvt(std::string const &in) { 
    std::stringstream buff(in);
    std::pair<int, int> ret;
    buff >> ret.first >> std::ignore(1) >> ret.second;
    return ret;
}
```

If your inputs may be something other than numbers, you can pretty easily keep them as strings, with something like:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> cvt(std::string const &in) { 
    std::stringstream buff(in);
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> ret;
    std::getline(buff, ret.first, ':');
    std::getline(buff, ret.second);
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can apply that to the entire input array with `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > pairs; // or std::pair<std::string, std::string>

std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::back_inserter(pairs), cvt);
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
using int_pair = std::pair<int, int>;
std::string input_array[] = { "12:000", "55:22" };
std::vector<int_pair> pair_vector;
std::transform(std::cbegin(input_array), std::cend(input_array),
    std::back_inserter(pair_vector), [](std::string const& str)
        -> int_pair {
        auto const& it = std::find(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), ':');
        return std::make_pair(std::stoi(std::string(str.begin(), it)), std::stoi(std::string(it+1, str.cend())));
});

// Let's display the results
for (auto const& pair : pair_vector) {
    std::cout << "First = " << pair.first << ", Second = " << pair.second << '\n';
}
```

This will output:

> First = 12, Second = 0
>   First = 55, Second = 22

As demonstrated [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe72feb7eb8df7ae)

Comment: I know people that say c++11 is like a new language.  When I see the features used like this I believe them.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't get it

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh! Edited my answer to reflect your comments (and stick to OP's input)